# How to change primary color in Ionic 5 programmatically?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

Currently my app-component routes to a split-layout which routes to the other pages. In the settings page my workaround is to change the accent color like this:

```
changeAccentColor() {
    console.log('Accent-color changed to: ', this.selectedAccentColor);
    document.body.style.setProperty('--accentColor', this.selectedAccentColor);
    document.body.style.setProperty('--toggleHead', '#ffffff');
  }
```

The color is assigned like this:

```
<ion-toggle style='--handle-background-checked:var(--toggleHead); --background-checked:var(--accentColor)'>Umschalten</ion-toggle>
```

and elsewhere like this:

```
.active-link {
    --ion-text-color: var(--accentColor);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

While this approach somewhat works it seems really hacky to me, because I can't use Ionic's normal way to handle colors anymore.

Is there are way to directly change the primary color during runtime and if not what is the best alternative?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Change the colour of the toggle?

Comment: you can define colors in css just like: `ion-toggle {
  --background: #000;
  --background-checked: #7a49a5;

  --handle-background: #7a49a5;
  --handle-background-checked: #000;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way of changing styles dynamically in **Angular** is using **[ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)**

But since it doesn't work on **ion-toggle** in your case, you can **directly bind** the **color variables** to the style and **change it** like you want anywhere in your code like this:

**in your .ts file:**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.selectedAccentColor = 'blue';
   this.toggleHeadColor = 'red';
}

changeAccentColor() {
    this.selectedAccentColor = 'green';
    this.toggleHeadColor = 'yellow';
}
```

**And in your .html file:**

```
<ion-toggle style='--handle-background-checked:{{toggleHeadColor}}; --background-checked:{{selectedAccentColor}}'>Umschalten</ion-toggle>
```